# send email using gmail smtp server

Tags: html

I want to send an email straight from my webpage, but I don't have access to an smtp server. I know that you can use `smtp.gmail.com` to do the outgoing stuff, and I have a gmail account.

My question is, can I use javascript, html5 or something of the like to send an email? I don't want to use javascript's `mailto` tool to open the default mail client, I want to do everything in-browser. Do you have to download AJAX to use AJAX to do it (I have heard of people doing it with ajax). I don't really want to download and use PHP, because I don't have a server or the time to learn it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, not in pure Javascript,html. Sending email requires server-side processing.
and you dont need to download ajax ( **Asynchronous JavaScript and XML**) like you dont need to download javascript

Comment: with only ajax it wont possible you need to use the server-side languages

Comment: @RileyH if you are using the php than try the [php mailer](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/wiki/ExamplesPage) its very simple to apply

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it with javascript or ajax alone. Try using a server side language like php. There are lot of free libraries in php for this. [PHP Mailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) and [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org) are some good examples. You can handle these libs simply if you had some base in PHP.